# Sequence Search given a key

Tags: javascript

Determine if the characters of the key appear in order (although, not necessarily contiguously) in the sequence. My code is returning true for all of them and I can't figure out what to do.

```js
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        if (!sequence.includes(key.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(sequenceSearch('arcata', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('c1a2t3', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('cta', 'cat')); //false
console.log(sequenceSearch('caat', 'cat')); //true
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution. This version will keep track the appearing order of key in sequence

```
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {
    let i = 0;
    for(let j = 0; j < sequence.length && i < key.length; j++)
       if (sequence[j] === key[i]) i++;
    return (i === key.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to utilize regex, it might not be the fastest way but it's short and easy enough:

```js
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {
    return new RegExp([...key].join('.*')).test(sequence);
}

console.log(sequenceSearch('arcata', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('c1a2t3', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('cta', 'cat')); //false
console.log(sequenceSearch('caat', 'cat')); //true
```

Basically it's testing `/c.*a.*t/` while `cat` is passed. So the order matters but the things inbetween don't

Comment: I'm actually not allowed to use regex

Answer (score 1):

Some verbose approach. Running two loops, while tracking sample word's position and testing only remaining piece of sample with next letter of the key.

```js
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {

    var s = 0;

    keyloop:
    for (var k = 0; k < key.length; k++) {

        seqloop:
        for (var j = s; j < sequence.length; j++) {
            if (sequence[j] === key[k]) {
                s = j+1;
                if (k < key.length - 1) {
                    continue keyloop;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

console.log(sequenceSearch('arcata', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('c1a2t3', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('cta', 'cat')); //false
console.log(sequenceSearch('caat', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('acaat', 'cat')); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not need two loops (as I've done in my included snippet), but you optimally shouldn't process everything, if you don't need to. For example, given `sequenceSearch('catarcatatac', 'cat')`, I would expect it to find "cat" at the beginning and just stop looking at any characters found after that. You also don't need to process all of `key`. If you couldn't even find a match for `c` and we're at the end of `sequence`, we can just stop.

Thanks to an early `return` - and just being picky about how your loops operate - you can avoid walking through more than is necessary. For example... (see commented version of snippet afterwards for more details)

```js
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {
  const l = sequence.length;
  let i = 0;

  for (const keyChar of key) {
    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
      if (sequence.charAt(i) === keyChar) break;
    }
    if (i === l) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(sequenceSearch('arcata', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('c1a2t3', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('cta', 'cat')); //false
console.log(sequenceSearch('caat', 'cat')); //true
```

...And here's that same code with comments to further explain:

```js
function sequenceSearch(sequence, key) {
  const l = sequence.length; // Storing here to avoid a get operation on every inner loop
  let i = 0; // Scoping to the function, instead of the inner loop

  // For each character of `key` (don't care about index, so `for...of` seems appropriate)
  for (const keyChar of key) {

    // For each character of `sequence`
    // (Pick up where we left off searching for the last `keyChar`. `i` is still in scope)
    for (; i < l; i += 1) {

      // If we find a matching character, stop walking through sequence
      // (Move on to next character in `key`, or stop processing `sequence`, altogether)
      if (sequence.charAt(i) === keyChar) break;
    }
    
    // Past the end of `sequence`. So, no match
    if (i === l) return false;
  }

  // We can assume we matched everything if we reach here
  // (We didn't go past the end of `sequence`)
  return true;
}

console.log(sequenceSearch('arcata', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('c1a2t3', 'cat')); //true
console.log(sequenceSearch('cta', 'cat')); //false
console.log(sequenceSearch('caat', 'cat')); //true
```